# Make subsection and its content unbreackable

Tags: formatting, sectioning, subsection

#### I'm writying a book in latex and faced a problem linked to the subsection content breacking.

[image]

I know, I have to show some minimal example, but it's very copmlicated to do it (but I will try a bit later). [FULL PROJECT here](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)

**Thank you for any help**

## My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
 
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,gray](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\subsection{Levels of skills }

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
\skills{{Word/1}}\\
\skills{{\LaTeX/6}}\\
\skills{{C++/2}}\\
\skills{{Python/3}}\\
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
\draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
\draw[fill=white,gray](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
\node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\skills{{b/2}}
\skills{{a/1}}
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How to get rid of breacking subsection title and its content?

[image]

Comment: You question does not make any sense at all. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: just edited and showed what I would like to achieve

Comment: Don't put stuff in a float environment like `table` or `figure` if you don't want it to float. Replace it with the `center` environment, maybe. Though, the right side will probably be too high to fit on the rest of the page anyway.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I understand, I want **0.1 Levels of skills
1** to be it on the second page, not on the first one

Comment: A quick fix would be to issue `\pagebreak` beforehand. And I just tested it, the `tabular` would just fit. If it's just a bit higher it would take the subsection with it if it wasn't in a float. Otherwise your subsection is empty and TeX doesn't see a need to put in onto the next page. It tries to keep the subsection and the following paragraph on the same page but there is no paragraph following.

Comment: It seems you don't want that the tabular can float away from the section heading, so you should not use a `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `table` environment even with `[h!]` is a still a float than can move to another page, because:

1. The content is too big for the available space, and/or ...
2. The  space that LaTeX must add between the float and the main text make impossible fit a tabular that barely fits on the space.

For (1) the only solution is leave more space, or make the tabular smaller, no choice.

For (2) you can simply delete  `\begin{table}[h!]` and `\end{table}` since there are not any caption.

In your MWE, applying  the solution for  (2) is enough:

---

[image]

---

In the document of your first screenshot, I guess that you will need also the solution for (1),  extensively, I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you very much!